# Python Error. Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead, how to fix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My dataframe consists of two columns, speed and power.

```
X = df[('speed')]
y = df[('power')]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
```

But I am getting the error when I run

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-a16f7a4d5962> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
      2 clf = LinearRegression()
----> 3 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)



I tried X.reshape(1, -1).  I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.
```

Comment: `X = X.reshape((1, -1))`?

Comment: Still get an error message and also tried  X = X.values.reshape(1, -1)

Comment: double brackets...

Comment: Also tried double brackets but still error.

Comment: Show the full errors you get... [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the square brackets, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'power':np.random.uniform(0,1,100),
                  'speed':np.random.uniform(0,1,100)})

X = df[['speed']]
y = df['power']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=10)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.predict(X_train)[:5]
```

This will run ok.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you